# Ionic radio button not being Selected

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

I have two ionic checkbox I need to select the first one for the first time of visit the page, T have tried many but not being ..

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-50">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>{{opt1}}</ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="{{opt1}}" checked="true"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-50">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>{{opt2}}</ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="{{opt2}}" [disabled]="isDisabled"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I dont find any problem with this.

Comment: but it is not working in my project

Comment: Does it even show a radio button ?

Comment: radio button is showing but not being checked automatically